# VS Code issue detecting unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up my tests on a personal chess project, and whenever I configure VS Code to use the test files inside of the folder I want, it is not able to discover any tests in the folder despite my files exactly matching the syntax of which tests to select.

Here is what is inside my Chess_test file:

```
from unittest import TestCase, TestLoader
import sys
from ChessGame import ChessGame

class ChessTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        return super.setUp()
    
    def basic_run(self) -> None:
        game = ChessGame()
        t = "t"
        s = "s"
        self.assertEquals(s, t)
```

Chess_test is inside of the ChessTests folder, and when I go to the following tab and configure my tests to be inside of the ChessTests folder, nothing changes:

[image: screenshot]

Someone else on Stack Overflow had the same issue and they resolved it by adding pytest.ini to the folder, but no matter where I research, I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place `__init__.py` in your tests folder.
2. Make sure that your test method name starts with `test_`. For example, you can rename `basic_run` to `test_basic_run`.

I use the following codes, and it works well:

```
from unittest import TestCase, TestLoader
import sys
from ChessGame import ChessGame

class ChessTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        return super().setUp()
    
    def test_basic_run(self) -> None:
        game = ChessGame()
        t = "t"
        s = "s"
        self.assertEquals(s, t)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(ChessTests)
    runner = TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
```

[image]